# Steam API Returns blank json

Tags: json, api, steam, steam-web-api

Im trying to get a user's mann vs machine tour number using the Steam API.

`https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=api&SteamID=steamid`

but it returns a blank JSON. Has anyone got an idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that steam api dont user https protocol use http instead

`http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=api&SteamID=steamid`